# Refresh a Document Sent After Changing Template

Tags: docusignapi

Using Developer API account, if we create a template, send to a recipient and then make changes to the template, can we update the document already sent to a recipient?

When we make changes and revisit the link (even in a new browser) it shows the old version. Is it protected from changes or cached?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of changes you're doing in the template and what endpoint you are using?

Eric | DocuSign

Answer (score 0):

Once an envelope is created from a template, any changes to the template will not affect the envelope.

You can change an envelope if it has not yet reached a terminal state. But doing so is separate from changes to a template.